# Can't use bold face on 2nd level outline in Emacs org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, emacs-faces

I can't get bold formatting to work on 2nd level outlines in org-mode. E.g. the following

```
* First level
* First *level*
** Second level
** Second *level*
```

produces:

- First level
- First **level**

  - Second level
  - Second `*level*`

(i.e. the last item is not rendered in bold, and instead Emacs just renders the `*` characters)

Is this the expected behavior? How can I use bold face in outlines other than the top one?

Comment: Looks like a problem in the parser. I just noticed that putting two consecutive stars somewhere on the line just before your 2nd level heading makes the bold appear (but if you touch it, it vanishes). I'll post on the mailing list regarding this issue.

Comment: Thanks @LeVieuxGildas I saw they got back to you on your post: [BUG: Parsing consecutive stars](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/61364) I have been unsuccessful in using `\ast` or `\ast{}`. How am I supposed to use these commands in my example above?

Comment: I didn't answer back, but these do not fix your problem, as both bold *and* headlines require real stars. What the answer *does* suggest is that it's not a very important matter, since only the fontification engine is fooled by this (not export engines for instance). As a workaround, I suggest you just shift everything one to the right, to convert them into well-behaving 3rd level headers.